# multiwii drone highly unstable

Tags: brushless-motors, flysky, arduino-drone, gyro

i built a drone using multiwii 2.4
following are the components
arduino uno
1800 kv bldc motor
30 amp esc
mpu6050
flysky fsi6 transmitter and reciever
10 inch propeller

i uploaded the code and calibrated the esc properly .
after that when i see in the software whithout connecting the esc everything seems perfect
but when i see after connecting the esc i observe that the motor throttle indicator all motors give different readings which was not in the case of when i had disconnected the esc .
and the same when i connected the propeller and tried to fly the drone became very unstable and crashed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like you need to tune the PID feedback settings. The flight controller needs to know how much to speed up or slow down the motors to correct when it's not level. If the values are too low, it will act as if there's no stabilisation. If they're too high, it will overcorrect and oscillate wildly.

IIRC there were several guides to tuning PID values for Multiwii, and you should be able to find someone else's values to use as a starting point.